# How to increase a number of item label and decrease item number at same time? R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am working on a code bloke that create a vector but in this list I want to have fist item 19 times and second 18 times but labels must be "V1", "V2". To be more specific:

```
 c("V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1",
      "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V2", "V2", "V2",
      "V2", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V2",
      "V2", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3",
      "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V4",
      "V4", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V4",
      "V4", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5",
      "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V6", "V6", "V6",
      "V6", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V6",
      "V7", "V7", "V7", "V7", "V7", "V7", "V7", "V7", "V7", "V7", "V7",
      "V7", "V7", "V8", "V8", "V8", "V8", "V8", "V8", "V8", "V8", "V8",
      "V8", "V8", "V8", "V9", "V9", "V9", "V9", "V9", "V9", "V9", "V9",
      "V9", "V9", "V9", "V10", "V10", "V10", "V10", "V10", "V10", "V10",
      "V10", "V10", "V10", "V11", "V11", "V11", "V11", "V11", "V11", "V11",
      "V11", "V11", "V12", "V12", "V12", "V12", "V12", "V12", "V12", "V12",
      "V13", "V13", "V13", "V13", "V13", "V13", "V13", "V14", "V14", "V14",
      "V14", "V14", "V14", "V15", "V15", "V15", "V15", "V15", "V16", "V16",
      "V16", "V16", "V17", "V17", "V17", "V18", "V18", "V19" )
```

I want to create 19 of V1 and 18 of V2. Here is my code, I am able to create 19 times first item and so on but How can I create item labels and item number separately?

```
z <- c()
for (i in 19:1){

  k <- c(paste("V",i, sep = ""))

  k <- c(k,rep(k,i-1))

  z <- c(z, c(k))  

}
```

Comment: rep(paste0('V', 1:2), c(19, 18))

Comment: And to recreate the whole vector in the question you use `rep(paste0('V', 1:19),c(19:1))`

Comment: @akrun There is one more question in my mind, what if I want to create a vector which starts with V1 to V20 and next loop V2 to V20 and V3 to V20 until V20 remains, is it possible to do it with this same method? For example: c("V1", "V2", "V3" , "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20", "V2", "V3" , "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20",..........., "V20")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a slight variation on @arkun's comment:

```
rep(sprintf('V%d', 1:19), c(19:1))
```

Here I use `sprintf` to create the input vector, note that it is vectorized:

```
sprintf('V%d', 1:19)
[1] "V1"  "V2"  "V3"  "V4"  "V5"  "V6"  "V7"  "V8"  "V9"  "V10" "V11" "V12"
[13] "V13" "V14" "V15" "V16" "V17" "V18" "V19"
```

Where `%d` means that here an integer value should be replaced.

Next we call `rep`, where we have to remember (quote from `rep` documentation):

> ‘times’ A integer vector giving the (non-negative) number of
>                 times to repeat each element if of length ‘length(x)’, or
>                 to repeat the whole vector if of length 1.  Negative or
>                 ‘NA’ values are an error.

So passing it the vector `19:1` causes the first item to be repeated 19 times, the second 18 times, etc. Note that `19:1` creates a vector from 19 down to one.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's a really good way to go on, with one line

Comment: @PaulHeimstra , There is one more question in my mind, what if I want to create a vector which starts with V1 to V20 and next loop V2 to V20 and V3 to V20 until V20 remains, is it possible to do it with this same method?  For example:  c("V1", "V2", "V3" , "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20",
"V2", "V3" , "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20",..........., "V20")

Answer (score 1):

For the new question, we can loop over 1:20, and get the sequence from each number to 20, `unlist` and `paste` with 'V'.

```
paste0('V', unlist(lapply(1:20, function(i) i:20)))
```

Or we can use `rep` and remove some elements

```
v1<- 1:20 +rep(0:20, each=20)
paste0('V', v1[v1 < 21])
```

---

Posting my comment (and @rbm's comment) as a solution for the original question.

```
rep(paste0('V', 1:19),c(19:1))
```